# How to change the forward button to mean "double click" on the Wacom Bamboo One grahpics tablet?

Tags: graphics-tablet, bamboo

I've got a Wacom Bamboo One grahpics tablet.

I would like to change the forward button to mean "double click" as I was able to on the old WACOM Graphire pens.

In a "**Pen and Tablet**" program it allows me to change the meanings of clicks of the pen and can click and unclick functions of the buttons, but how do I tell it that the **front of the button should mean double click**?

[image]

Comment: I think "forward button" is a bit confusing, as some Wacom tablets have buttons for that on top of *the tablet itself*. It seems that you are referring to the buttons *on the stylus* (on the pen), right?

Comment: yes, the front of the button on the pen

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working today:

1. download and install the latest [drivers from Wacom](http://www.wacom.com/downloads/drivers.php) (released 2010-Jul-15), reboot
2. run "Bamboo preference file utility" and remove all preferences for yourself and all users
3. run "Bamboo preferences" program (may need to run as administrator on win7, vista)

[image: bamboo prefrences dialog]